# How can I get all urls of the site?

Tags: php, jquery, python, ruby-on-rails

How can I get all urls of the site by any programming language or software?

For example, I have site http://getmoneygettraffic.com/ and I know there are some other pages like http://getmoneygettraffic.com/48h 
How can I find links for the other pages? If I know only domain -  http://getmoneygettraffic.com/

UPDATE: (It's my site) Can I get all urls of the site without rake(ROR) or going to ftp or cPanel ?

I have tried this stackoverflow.com/questions/857653/… and this one stackoverflow.com/questions/131989/… and this too stackoverflow.com/questions/16619687/

Also, I have tried -> https://code.google.com/p/knock/ , cool stuff, but it's looking only for subdomains if I'm not mistaken. I need right part of the url, not the left.

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857653/get-a-list-of-urls-from-a-site  and  this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131989/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-subdomains-of-a-domain and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619687/list-of-domains-being-managed-by-a-dns-server

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is you can't do it if the website uses URL Rewriting which rules you don't have. If the website is yours and doesn't use complex rewriting you could try browsing the root directory to retrieve ".php" files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this with ruby on rails, if you own this website/ have access to server, you can do `rake routes` in the root of your application and get the whole list of routes that are available for it.

Otherwise, I am not so sure that you would be able to get an exhaustive list unless you have access to the application code

Comment: thank you, if I don't own the site. I just can programme on some languages, so that's why I added different programing languages :) Maybe, there is a way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sitemap option to get all the urls

Comment: Thank you, didn't work in this case :)